# wpf 3d I can see the shpe when camera is front but when camera is back i cant

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf3DTest.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"     Title="WPF 3D Test" Height="400" Width="400">
<Grid Background="Black"
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Viewport3D x:Name="viewport" Grid.Row="1" >
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camera" FarPlaneDistance="50" LookDirection="0,+10,0" 
                UpDirection="0,0,1" NearPlaneDistance="0" Position="0,-5,0"
                FieldOfView="50" />

        </Viewport3D.Camera>

        <ModelVisual3D x:Name="model">
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <Model3DGroup x:Name="group" >
                    <AmbientLight Color="DarkGray" />


                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="0,7,0" />

                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="0,-7,0" />


                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="4,8,5" />
                    <GeometryModel3D>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                            <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,0,-1 -1,0,1 1,0,1 1,0,-1" TriangleIndices="0,1,2"/>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial Brush="Blue"/>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    </GeometryModel3D>
                </Model3DGroup>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

hi this is my first question. ı hope to find.
ı can see the shape when the camera is front.
but when ı change camera to back ı cant.

ı think if it is cause of light. ı add 2 more diffrent place. but i cant

camera front

```
<PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camera" FarPlaneDistance="50" LookDirection="0,-10,0" 
                UpDirection="0,0,1" NearPlaneDistance="0" Position="0,5,0"
                FieldOfView="50" />
```

camera back

```
<PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camera" FarPlaneDistance="50" LookDirection="0,+10,0" 
                UpDirection="0,0,1" NearPlaneDistance="0" Position="0,-5,0"
                FieldOfView="50" />
```

both of camera is looking at shape
thanks.

Comment: I don't know a lot about WPF 3D, but sounds like your square is single sided.  You should be able to experiment with the normals property of the `MeshGeometry3D` to make it double sided.

Comment: Welcome!  I posted an answer below, but please update your question with an actual question.  Here are the question asking guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing [back-face culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling).

> Backface culling is an important part of how a 3D engine performs visibility checks. Its purpose is to detect polygons that are invisible in a particular scene – that is, polygons that face away from the viewer.

[From Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131773/a_compact_method_for_backface_.php)

In most 3D systems, only the front face is visible.  The front face is determined by the winding order or the points.  In the case of the case the [MeshGeometry3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.meshgeometry3d(v=vs.110).aspx), the winding order for the front face is counter clockwise.  If you were to reverse the order of the points in the "TriangleIndices" property:

```
<MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,0,-1 -1,0,1 1,0,1 1,0,-1" TriangleIndices="2,1,0"/>
```

Then you should see the triangle only from the "back" camera and it would be invisible in the "front" camera.